# Find the antiderivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{(1-iz)^2}$, which I strongly believe to be $\frac{i}{1-iz} + C$ by using the simple rule of differentiation, but the note says $\frac{-i}{1-iz} + C$ instead and I think it is a typo. Could anybody confirm whether this is a typo or not?

Comment: What is the antiderivative of a complex function?

Comment: Think of it as slalom, taking the path to the left or to the right of some important points makes all the difference in the world of the value of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\frac{-i}{1-iz})'=-i ((1-iz)^{-1})'=-i(-1)(1-iz)^{-2}(-i)=(1-iz)^{-2}$.

So it is not a typo !

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I do not understand why there is $(-1)$ after the second equality sign.

Comment: Oh I got it...... since it can be represented as being raised to the power of negative one